# YarnClient unable to find application in a query

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to get all applications thru all queries in Yarn cluster using `YarnClient`. I have default query under the root query (default setup).

This sample:

```
yarn
    .getAllQueues() //get all queries (size == 1)
    .stream()
    .findFirst()
    .get()
    .getQueueName() //get the name of the only query == default
```

will result in `"default"`, then

```
yarn
    .getAllQueues()
    .stream()
    .findFirst()
    .get()
    .getApplications()
```

will result in empty list, but

```
yarn
    .getQueueInfo( //returns Queue info searched by name which is default in this case
        yarn
        .getAllQueues() //returns all queues
        .stream()
        .findFirst() //find first and only queue which is default
        .get()
        .getQueueName()) //get it's name which is String "default"
    .getApplications() //returns all applications as a list of size one
```

will give me list of size == 1 (I'm running one yarn applications at the cluster)

My YARN cluster is at version `2.8.0`, I tried to use YARN binaries for `YarnClient` `2.7.1`, `2.8.0`, `2.8.1`
Am I doing something wrong or it's just long preserving bug in the api?